# Sorting numerically in a comma-delimited file with Unix

Tags: unix, csv, sorting, hp-ux

I've got a comma-separated file that looks like this:

```
100,00869184
6492,8361
1234,31
200,04071
```

I want to use `sort` to sort this file *numerically* by the *first column only*.

**Desired Result:**

```
100,00869184
200,04071
1234,31
6492,8361
```

How do I achieve this using sort? It seems like the commas are being treated like thousands separators instead of delimiters even when I call them out as such.

Both `sort -t',' -n` and `sort -t',' -nk1'` give me this:

```
1234,31
200,04071
6492,8361
100,00869184
```

Sorting by the default (no parameters) or using `sort -t','` gives me this:

```
100,00869184
1234,31
200,04071
6492,8361
```

And sorting as a number `sort -n` gives me this:

```
1234,31
200,04071
6492,8361
100,00869184
```

**How can I use sort to achieve my desired result?**

Edited to add: This is for a one-time operation to create a sorted list of about 7 million lines, so workarounds or other unorthodox methods are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: the examples I see [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/sort.shtml) seem to show the `-t` option as having a space between the `-t` and the character

Comment: First thought - use cut. It selects only a particular column, based on a given separator. Also "Artem Ice"'s answer with tr. I love tr. I am too lazy to write and test this, though. Cheers!

Comment: Possible same for tab char: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly a dirty workaround, but I figured out a way to do this thanks to @slhck's tip about locales. If a better answer comes along that would be more helpful to others, I'll certainly accept it since this pretty much only works for my specific problem.

I set the locale to Spanish (Bolivian) so that the commas were treated like decimal points, then standard numeric sorting did the trick.

```
$ export LC_NUMERIC="es_BO.utf8"

$ cat test.csv
100,00869184
6492,8361
1234,31
200,04071

$ sort -n test.csv
100,00869184
200,04071
1234,31
6492,8361
```

Comment: Ah see, I would have suggested using a German locale or similar. Can't think of anything else right now without being able to test it or what tools you have available, since this is a pretty rare Unix version.

Comment: @slhck That seems to be the crux of most of the problems I get stuck on in UNIX :) Thanks for your help in getting me to a solution, regardless.

Answer (score 6):

GNU's `sort` does this by default:

```
$ cat test
100,00869184
6492,8361
1234,31
200,04071

$ gsort -nt',' < test
100,00869184
200,04071
1234,31
6492,8361
```

Version:

```
$ gsort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.19
```

---

There's a caveat though: If your sorting does not work as expected, then your [`locale` is probably set to something different](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021) than `C`. Why is this? `locale` defines sorting and interpretation of letters, numbers, decimal characters et cetera.

To check this, just enter `locale` in a Terminal. Is `LC_NUMERIC` set to `en_US.UTF-8`, maybe? This would explain the wrong sort order. Set it back to `C`:

```
export LC_NUMERIC=C
```

Then, try your `sort` command again. If you want to set your global `locale` to `C`, do this with:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: I don't have access to GNU in my environment. Is it something I could easily get then remove when I am finished? HMU in chat if someone would like to help me do this... I'm quite the UNIX newbie.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a `locale` issue. But what's `sort --version` for you, actually?

Comment: sort --version gives me an illegal argument. `--` commands haven't worked for me in the past either. I checked the man page and there's no version called out explicitly, but it does list "HP-UX 11i Version 2: August 2003" if that helps at all. My LC_NUMERIC is set to "C".

Comment: German locale for example would use `,` as a decimal separator. I've never used HP-UX though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `-g` option which is suppose to perform numeric sorting.

Try:

```
sort -t',' -g <whatever>
```

Comment: Isn't `-n` numeric sorting? -g gives me an illegal option.

Comment: `-g` is the `general-numeric-sort` option and should actually be available in any recent version of `sort`. @dpatchery

Comment: This is at my place of work so I almost definitely do not have a recent version :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the delimeter:

```
cat commafile | tr , " " | sort -n
```

- should help you.